# HP Probook 4440s system restore partition erased, now it freezes at boot screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, freeze, bootloader

I erased the system restore partition on my HP Probook 4440s laptop, now it hangs at the first logo when booting. If I don't change it from trying to boot from the hard drive, there is no error, it just freezes at the first screen. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that it is EFI based, but I did leave the EFI partition untouched. I just erased the system restore partition and installed two other OSs on the free space.

Now I can still boot into Windows and my other OSs if I leave my thumb drive plugged in with Chameleon bootloader installed on it. I've tried installing Chameleon on the internal drive, but it still freezes at the very first screen on power up. How do I fix this? I am not going to get any DVDs to make restore media, so please don't even suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

I can make no promises, but try preparing a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) That page has links to image files for both media type, but you'll need a Windows equivalent of the Linux `dd` command to prepare a USB flash drive (or you could do this from Linux, if you have a Linux installation on any computer). If you can boot rEFInd and if it then enables you to boot Windows, you could install rEFInd on your hard disk. This will enable you to boot, albeit through rEFInd, which will add some time to your boot process. Another option might be to open an Administrator Command Prompt window and type the following command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

I can't promise that this will work, but it might. If it does work, it will boot straight to Windows, without involving rEFInd.

Comment: I did the bcedit command first and got this error, "The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The system cannot find the file specified." I copied and pasted into an Command Prompt opened using administrator's power. I'll try rEFInd next, but like I said I did install cameleon onto the internal drive and it had no effect. Also I am able to boot using chameleon from my usb drive, just to make that clear. Thanks for the help!